# Google Maps Works on Localhost, Fails in IIS

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, iis

I have a google map application that runs perfectly fine on local host. When I publish the application on IIS, the google api key v2 returns a 404 error.

I do not have google key, I am running without a key on a .net 4.0 Framework. Is the error because of a setting in IIS or I would need a key to query google REST API.

Below is an excerpt of my code -

```
   private string GetLatitudeLongitudeFromAddress(string url)
    {
        string latitudeLongitude = string.Empty;
        WriteToFile(path, "Entering GetLatitudeLongitudeFromAddress - url in parameter = "+url);
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = null;
            bool is_geocoded = true;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.Method = "GET";
            //WriteToFile(path, "request response = " + request.GetResponse().ToString());
            response = request.GetResponse();

            WriteToFile(path, "response returned = "+response.ToString());
            string lat = "";
            string lng = "";
            string loc_type = "";
            if (response != null)
            {
                XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(response.GetResponseStream());
                XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

                // get response status
                XPathNodeIterator statusIterator = navigator.Select("/GeocodeResponse/status");
                while (statusIterator.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (statusIterator.Current.Value != "OK")
                    {
                        is_geocoded = false;
                    }
                }

                // get results
                if (is_geocoded)
                {
                    XPathNodeIterator resultIterator = navigator.Select("/GeocodeResponse/result");
                    while (resultIterator.MoveNext())
                    {


                        XPathNodeIterator geometryIterator = resultIterator.Current.Select("geometry");
                        while (geometryIterator.MoveNext())
                        {
                            XPathNodeIterator locationIterator = geometryIterator.Current.Select("location");
                            while (locationIterator.MoveNext())
                            {
                                XPathNodeIterator latIterator = locationIterator.Current.Select("lat");
                                while (latIterator.MoveNext())
                                {
                                    lat = latIterator.Current.Value;
                                    //Console.WriteLine("Latitude value = {0}", lat);
                                    latitudeLongitude = lat;
                                }

                                XPathNodeIterator lngIterator = locationIterator.Current.Select("lng");
                                while (lngIterator.MoveNext())
                                {
                                    lng = lngIterator.Current.Value;
                                    //Console.WriteLine("Longitude value = {0}", lng);
                                    latitudeLongitude = latitudeLongitude + "#" + lng;
                                }
                                XPathNodeIterator locationTypeIterator = geometryIterator.Current.Select("location_type");
                                while (locationTypeIterator.MoveNext())
                                {
                                    loc_type = locationTypeIterator.Current.Value;
                                }
                            }


                        }
                    }
                    //Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in Calculating Coordinates Address - {0}", ex.Message + "GetLatitudeLongitudeFromAddress");
        }
        WriteToFile(path, "Exiting GetLatitudeLongitudeFromAddress - value returned  = "+ latitudeLongitude);
        return latitudeLongitude;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

developer license is not guaranteed to have high availability, so maybe that's the reason of why you're getting 404's.

Comment: Is there a way I can get a demo key to test if the problem is with google maps being keyless or IIS? I have tried developer key and I cannot make it work.

Comment: Thank Jay..I am unable to paste my HTML code, I get error that I am overdue the character limit that per post. I don't see an option to paste code as I did in my original question...